# Not able to get the image base64 url from javascript to c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

this my javascript code and below I have attached my c# code for the backend

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="WebCam.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        Webcam.set({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 90
        });
        Webcam.attach('#webcam');
        $("#btnCapture").click(function () {
            Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
                $("#imgCapture")[0].src = data_uri;
                $("#btnUpload").removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        });
        $("#btnUpload").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CS.aspx/SaveCapturedImage",
                data: "{data: '" + $("#imgCapture")[0].src + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) { }
            });enter code here
        });
    });`
```

c# code

```
`[WebMethod()]
public static bool SaveCapturedImage(string data)
{
    string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy hh-mm-ss");
 
    //Convert Base64 Encoded string to Byte Array.
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data.Split(',')[1]);
 
    //Save the Byte Array as Image File.
    string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Captures/{0}.jpg", fileName));
    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageBytes);
    return true;
}`
```

request json:

```
{"data": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF8AAABLCAYAAAAWC1t4AAAgAElEQVR4XsW9CZhd91nm Z3l7ltV3dpLVaVdlmTL yLbsWM7dhKvsZ2QxNBkIYFOmoZpQoaBp6ebzpAZpgnTMPDAQz9M95NOCCRAFmTH2MFbEsfxblmxLcnatyrVXnX3e889Z37vKck4xokDDM9I1iO56ta55/z/3/J 7/d / t89ENvi/xcZGmLrJFoWd1PmdepWiaIrOM4NhAlrJtyrB2kLJ9etHbDsVxqxJqVpmXLrlUaK9aTdqwT9FnLTVku2bVGs2bpdI FgW e1zFLdSyop62Qq1t9sWFBqmTNlcgsGZjn5CyfmbCEm7N2pmnpbtGc7qKF0Zx5XccSyZKFXtVcz7d0ImOVVmg5P2EtP7Ks07aEn7Ru2DHHihYlO5ZoZnhty0I3a5ZIWBT5ljSPp2vZst 2/hb/n81atVM3L FbIrvGHr3/Mfv2wacscEpW9NOWXaxbOpOxgYn1dtP7329prpFKehYEgWX8vNXM5WsV7tG3Lvfd6TYt47F TsLCbtKcZMMinj3pdK0dedbutK0T1cypR akua8Oz 13zfnpf3NrlGictr5C2SrWNjfftNbsjBUL3EQqb FKaDU2IM2fYli3kAd39UaJnJV6PKuu8MA8hBc0eNOktavcWqLPuk7IgwdWYnHavD70s ZwA76T5WYjq/IghVzWwk6K61XY7Ix52UELnbQlUzlr1U9Yxg2sUV0xLzdgTc zvqzLw3R4UJd7S9tSvWq V7JkOmH1 rKxttZJ5o2tsZyX57qBpVMF63a7LIpZNcQOHDYtbdYI25bk3iLL2Dcf/YGdqK1Yls3OuwkLKmlLpVL2gX/1XnNYUHbCum0WNOLV3ZRZtmCdzqLVA9cyubJFYY0NDqwVunzd4W8WN FZNuFard3lPTC0MGuNoGm mbVbGCAb5vzsJ2 OCoXAOrWO a2WlcttW l4VuAmO7U2FpXDirDAtG tVtsil 9leKAEFwyw5CC0NA/s8DthTa4cmp/sw6IDqzkNG0jksQI20A9Z9MCSIR6UylqUCCzghlyP90ixEUHC2vWUdRIFNqbBoqWs2Vy0VKZonovluTwEm  kWIjQs1SzY2Euw6KmLJVOWdBu4iU5vKZtaRcLCx08oWFhmMTDPPMi1xrdjEUYj0UrloiylvAS1nFdmzo ay 9esS8VNI2n3eObSmP4R3atGz8bB08KMNiRi3WiYXtOto04zmz1uJ5k6xop9GyDsbre3iiPC3tsjx1NttlnRyrYe0dr8H78vO8hrBgzkd/ c5odh5Lz/g24rR4yNDquLfDLnnsU8eVB5g5uH27EVjE3xgyb7BixTzWlUtapY5LsSB omypRNO6/H8mlbCF5hK732sFbr7NRiXSvRZ0sFCXG6xzzeyQNVrTls3grlGKny9YMddr1XYL66iw G3rKRRY2AXrzfVbu83DYf1dFs7j32HCIbSwEGEUb4AsM8W/ZQjJNO/Bw7YbHn nWWjZX5f37rNavUIYSbNxLs/I3rC5EYs7365bQ9cg3Gax5cjJ2ND4Wn4ubU4Tb/AKRAGMjXsIG3VjqXgNa4sntpq8Kp 0Thsj5qoN7sMndMvKE6xTFeN2QqydLZIxY1Hm/PIv3sZdJW0xXGF357layQrsTNSsWipbZCFCy/AgLjflNmrm9WmbuywAD5JJWbGLR/AmLSzLZ5d7CCUBPn6aRc6w6f3pPJZqthwsW39q0upe02rVuuX9EmEmiBeg08GyClle1yVOYjF4nRlWHuW5eeK338ESh81pLFuBEJMihCn8 FhUwEb6vm9NeRWbbF2 7ssQsJgwtC65ymNj6hFWiJU7XXKYLJ/c5jj8UVhIYVitjh04Om37Z5YsWV22fG/aLr3kIsw7zfUy5JcC9zDGgrOxeB9rzHUIp7yH4ZUeRuqwFq7uv9siTLI HUIv3tUiJIZ58kMD4yFUBXhtg2V0fuFn38djdCzNg/s9hAJuPNkl7rJwzXCZHcqRF1dshDdsVOp2Oh1ZIZmx4fFem1 YIxSReNlr1yMEEOPSJDrF5BY77uD bdxesTfP95q4cbs7Z31sSCtBIm1USUChuR3yAJbYClh8uSNhwmGToibegCG0EyRZFtnxAyw7ZW0sRw/dIh4nWOQCVubyNRmA8X7pLD9PTE/zsw2uF2DVKRZBnpTAIx1ySV72yR6zDmx21 YbTbvvwcesxgJNcn9t7mXTtots6wWjvAdwpNZlUV1LFXtI0gNs6qoREE0IPz0Wtck/KS8OQ8oxsvgsOaXZqhNyGuZlSvGmpDCeSoWYHxAtfuFD740Od5etJ8 DLLMw/ZN2YHbZhnp6sBQenuTY5y5bthiCPho232TnM8JGLUuSYF38Lo0FrjhNc5MsDN6Rz/SQcEBIvGlPoWgdEErgO7FVeO2kleTinSVCDEkItyglC1ZvdonvKVusLZiXLMZhJAGaaLaqttR2rDcbWQJXih82yvDeIBkFGN6ni5V5WB3PZjlQCqYYo6AGMTdi08k2VsrkcArPXB/rd T6WGWT2Ky4g9U /8oB 96Le2wgJORme zoqUPWxVpvu/Za2zI gAGwsDxvqsLzAQiaAdfyeuOEn8oVMCQyOgjM4Z5rCkkkYB8vUY5aWG7ilRiP8hYx33F8W1w6bc6GKz4WDY4QP2tz1g9Uyw5NWK1WsOHSOHGYnfJOW69bxW3nLcVj5NMtUEOHmJnnrkE67HaI6/pYZ8Ij7rLAbV7p8wZ5rFnunnCwdCMMAWW9Fp6EBRNGSd4F/iSJl3N8DTQE2vB5gDavwdPJDzU2DgsqjmFZJAlBzzSxGqvVxqdyaTYDJANsDAEEOWCfg WyIyRPwg6mrXBUYF2CLHFW13cISYSLNm4fdDJKGbbYDOzh7zxnx2enbBSvmAaxjfWP2aETR 2db3 nbd0yiEexoW6GZw8IPdy/F1pTO9fGaNP9eDx5hYt1ukBL8gJvhbHxbyy8xaZnec AlQmxni4e2gkAGuefe00UANu89IDlCkDAbs4qczfZTXe/1/JXhrbvLw7YGuevLZk/bGH1pBW4SJLEkgWjK9EFWH2LJGxYU67oYMEtLD9jKfKI2yE54rJdLLWH77lhhRvhtYrNYCMX5OQSr80H5OqmQEUJ4n0I7MxkAG8gFy1oY4UQguVWec skmuWBN3JkapYXB4ogTVzW4AEs3KiGMdiQd0mcC6Fdzk8PEAQ6wNN4R1pdrbWXCbWg2j4QoABfePeh2252rL1owM2P3XCUvmcrdSadu3OK 2cDWvIRcDqRgPv1oLiUdx3hdBjNTaTOiYiZzgNYGyxNw7VnZB7JNTV8fok79MmhzZ8wMii8g0bSFRxtr/tE1GSJDA39awNT/TZQjhsM61LbM22D9u7fz5ju/7UbGTlBStkH7fOwgO2bjQLgmlaPlfCvRZwc IrCcvFEjK4GbiG3SfGYaEJHjId5glVZqV ICJwLEGGUfLOpIskXza73rB8iYWkYBKG8il0Wp0VEjWbB9qo1thkrSpelkmDVFjEDJsXEKuzoA4PlOTgaSwhi8/7YggZHjrJxrZw8cBTuMNL8RxPYRILVeHj8XUDNIRsUpZ7/c7jT9uju/fY4MCwVQm7fUODNj27ZHfedq2NDY5aAe quDXuH itZ S9WgJboTaBjSd8sgRWA3x4WL jsETIcUBIrZZyUiFGf2nu08JFEjTf23rX30Uzc9 hgHrFeoFXHXBw2Oy3ZuI2czdfZtWpig1FXydeAQk7r9jJlTm7gMo2U8gQahxbk NiKdBPaogkxoOwu4ugiv4iiQ8UEygUEAcjVX55LBXUk8ZSkzGUw4pdqlk/F1ewuBIhp82ikgtaFGvcICkUK6L4I1FGQRII6 H eFPYIgEr2WVIpF3LgLm7SqhJjADoKFdoeDWuTe4ixiixBxSKLkUUT8 GaauJ/9Qxyl8Hjhywbz/ fOxtJRb71JEpu3jrOXb99VfFi00eZcFIuISxkPepC/ezuSGvb7UDnDkBouNFZHCf5 gAYEJCan25AezF 4gIDWqSLs/UJkdluI6z8fZd0dTp 2xtURDylOWwqCQ3PNfqNSdzPiENZGN7rd45AiSctqLDojgLUA ymrytG 63GnF5bnHRRgf77dyxPvIBGBuL9MjsQ6U XC6yJVBQgkVJ 8R30EARV8R5ic1EQmCu4GHIgkWgGAfkksIylSC7JCn8IU7IRQwjWSQRU 1iyipzwO1Uybi4ipY0GxiyELgPmxwQRkssbweLZOH5lzbbZ MCrDJMU5SBXtyQpMmGHZ06acVy2Z5 cg/Jdsauu/oqWzOKUagGEJoklwkAe/zdJF7rfpfbFTyLZE/kaBCSojZhll0NKfhCFrfJ10N 10FSYR0Iy8Z3BI hHhI8l3P59R P2rUlK d7bSXLxepKCLUYFkbdActkRywVnOQGKfMpsZ2gykWo5twmBQk3T6VbFy1B0TNJgVSnwKpxA1snzoF/kYUlbcPEWnIA4SY9jAtOWSGfBl1h0x0itku8JFwRxlkmFoSfzQjC8agqfhoNCiLVCuQQ XWa9wygM8gM8WapyvFZdBk7bgs644FBOAGv9YIcnkJVjmVHYHplCOWZlFdkYeCvcuQH8kuDkIRjESKUTKE2uJ4jioDn8ojNXa7ZprbJE55a/FvVVSfgmgCPCE8NCT11PKAL4mvJI9n/JuvoQks0lgErchuMIWotWqPG9wmLGZCdc/m7bokyLnG2BbxIEMvqp7lR4WxoAPEf7giJo0UoyNvMyePWKjStUPJwK3ZPCwq cwg7wXLHBrC0Za5Rma9Zv5e1BR63f 0N5tUh4MC2F 64Hm9p2slTL9r1W4h5qXmSN6GH5JVkIyoRtAIbWMNqFAzIGtQFZEhW1sXlFyBn8ukSJT/LouILD0mDcsI2mBlk5cIbhaAVJ8mCEAJy1oMXyb/4Gl4SEd/ThDTWi6 xwFw/R03S5ToO1EWDPz2FPluqUXvwPY/EGJEfup3ISnx9Hi4pycL7EWEIDgfLswakmcd6gdxZdDwMr2g1m/zdJdmyVhhKFQS2DFUTtFasToHJQ8QhzLnknddEYZsMnByEUQSj8kMJEmgWJDHXgBhaTll5AFcltOiN05TIkVsBKbAAhI86Wb4/C2cCFOO/Vc4HLxA3EsClNJfTNsKmdANie kO3P0qEMdhu/XCU9AW87gfySdBCc4DCktrgZJYbZfQ4YG8tOgh1i13d FUAjZCudLRzfNaD5SVxIWbII8EFl9lZQt5KvEOnBILmErDqWC1GfioiA3rkm8aXEOoSUnPF5EWhyNuW0UheF2Vdo77X8ZSU/BF2oCU8gxlrTy9U1 B2S2SaDtWxQDTLLiKvhCTF5pqsAmdTse6snKQZBfmd4kN69TwImgTh4jgETqdG257O8VZ3Uq9kEmEkulleJk8Ox VbUVxPyjgvi2qyIqlWcTFxiKYdopqxrBECqa AdhExeoqi88D9RDvgTceNHREsAybg8CvgmXbi7Zk11s1ewtY/yW74TyzyQEoapthM7Ee6oF4IYnrDjS0KxjZoJ6A7PJYINEQLglMEFWLLkrEgyIIYRSjmHUl aWp1ckTKUitrjxS9o5XedyXYHETHM7 EJowWuoUJVcXQ1P8Dpp4ldhKFph3i6FrwD1EcFYRmT3C8BzodI96prJSB/0V4usr1jcwnCbIqcsGpHyCMEbbxWDacFQuizzH64WOKpCInXrTelopy8K6OjfeeXsUxNh8EG9o2DJVaaVFYmhlbdQ/H4bxHIuKDdzzB3DwcNhYfpBags2cZ8ezNpDVwwVGEYc3YOEsYBO8rJjudat8bZgHzfJ9bt65xFrp221wqGwbnBnbuPkEHvESXjVnJYogcf9drEcVqI9VpkAoDTzLgxjz RO0SL2Esy5ekFXSJea2Hbh ApQ2DhchzmJR4lrwHLmILDLqiHKAWcSzwTuWVvHDZhXyZa4tKgTCS5wMcVmFkgizEOiYSeElVNgu10nDc9V4f70HxEaMlzoUl7yUnxdIIUwBj5fm5vBQgC 5qUsOWlhcgPEg8BFWlYCdOrUQntgDI tcf9sdURG6ANKNwjBly9ADo6rWQAFNQoSVbrexbR07 MTfWd7Zb0uLR62UWyA yrUoKugN9BRIjCtwG9ALacLRiTk8CdI8izuvtClCfIqM5DAbOgqy2WSFoUvsHRf1gXoOs G7eZ4lIiZcP7lF9augneK5D0QVH KpKYIFtlvCzoP0EtLWx4IkIxbGx PIP4A/OCYSNfWCmimewoMCDx4SqOBTQhYXJETE16EBqZJZNGqJLh4QsiGim7U5qkJ9Uc8qf0F1cbIEv0f8QEhC7RKaPSCu0FOHOCOKBTYRKp73jUv3uq0QQUJIvQ7G1FaCZofUm/CBqU01f0juzm23vScaKvdQMGHVLPoKhZOTGrB8kyScuNiaxavsqhvX23MP7iNT/7nlWzB oB2POL 8Mmv9fVSJwLs5qICBNDdVGrHjx2est0B5H1HROUWspY mStpOBYNWp1niZc 1m6 9FCuoWL7zGAl0Be/goUiOLTpEYgZ6oJcryytxQvVZ7EqlRQ7K2hN7PXv5yYN29Tuutx2bCR/tl2nKCMcTx1nfUs6zSpOkRk7w8aSwmSBEiGAjUVL0CC52sOoUxZzWt4mVqvJVgVSHRi q00TyUuJ0QFmK3TlQThfvaInJBS0l8Yh63CRROUE4ZOFDrFlFHTuIxdMEwogDoGfVx0saKsbIj5Uq66zIIRYW5HjHre JElw0maIkhzRTJm9SSaaAmPPiYWyt9ZQIPWTqgzOPQoot2cb dVgwttaesmIJGEY2rxPfUrkeLDW0pZmj1jcwQFEh6FbiaUfJF1vsxEoXa1yykf41du1177SoCnoI92NFp3j4Km1CKlK4EBfsnGNR6iqD4gUTSRbYwnyv/d5XCUOZndY7mbCDex6HLX0eEhD J9ewvlzNbrh6q4335ONmkE Poo7rJ1Xo8XxVoHJfvhQ3RVJsriiROAkALzMi8UBiYlS7AIY0dHeblqQq5gRAQJ2yUMUhVbu6UC02AWhCZIO3Imz2EhY7QNZQHgqVXKvTOiUyANwxaHXWfFuCxe0AUrpNFh522Hn/bTdGNejbQmIiruJquE5PT79FZP2IhewprLNC36jNL1FOL2Hh9VmbHBqmmsPl2dLhPt6IizVYvBykWBJLODZbt4GBofiNkk6/JVrbbMG/0PyJEaseeQJWsGXXXHk1jOU0fBABk7K7kFliA8DO6Yp5zQoLw7/Jel6yNw4DqajfjtUvsP yy7Xp9rBdsCWwPd 7l8162gruKV6/iItTyLSVhDu2eU3CLtu5wUaGRi2X6LGeNXkIQjgpaooWMThHKHL4kwBCB oFE1oEOUXYiayLvYIcofAXYbUpJW1V2SxkiBcrzKhfoLohSSHaYA08PF09gqogp5JtvU2eIY8SuZTB6ysNQASQk01XjnGufOd1kUtsm8gCX2g0RPRmVdWRR PiIOUP27XXvM2e P6LtlIhJxDecqUhqAbiIwudz2M9oNzF2jx9YLgLkMmB04QTkFGNgqsnM2KVLp6TvNq2X5myp7 9l8V40a7cdrH1FrNxNUxaJAFWsHj6A92jVkxAyRJjFVtDqOMmCTOT2WHHgg327ELKvvxFoCT5Itn5Jm58mAc7DDjIw72AVOS5oDPIJJ5X7TK4oDgXJa0fY7nysvPtjhtusDzIQwRDSMszrX4zr OiMbT1ifMRELJLFd4BqeRJbB0WX SaeKk6XA1gmA3C60FHSfibDrCzSQesxFo2RdbheXXyYJMQKBa2CV1CoQ8TsIIhAQp4rXPXPXcqUhmsNA9L2xDuvJBLWQZVQQomUZzMBZddaM8/ux8XHrKT9SGy1BY2pw/iDJTkzZLdDwOzjmC9FPNViqgqze4S7B7uXed6DUglPxohfo/Aze 1cvG0XXXxFbg BVUFlqevaDk1t7tTthTsJQmLYuamySUddTx4r0q4xTrl8 z 3U27/yvH6DfvpjI9Qmw/jbcpbNVI6qQ7QovqhBUSdR9VJIZKzUGIqBGaVEWnUFW4gyTefrv08p1208WTdvkEiTRFrUO90QH5FTIgqpikW228qOGvFA2IAqOThNlIhRhthmhwgDJVNe8RAVRY FAcFR7WqCnMsOggvRDaugP6W0E9ofwQ1yl3vO8G4DgEGZBQhRJ53xLwMQm6WTV8Lwc8 sBPfcC 9fBLdqgGq9g9l/wwZOWLzWYPmI2RvZfqeyzd2E vkj4nTe/Dc1SEA1uxDR6qQhVLMsUJYUBdwtcJG 1P2XkXbAcF9FpvfoNtu85s79MY3qI4y6Ns0jR09FTc4lNRFNG9mg2otKOL7CsPTtmzL /nAebop7LoICV4RRaGJgwVsr9y3IJcn9V5OIrLWNqh5nsWbJ1gs5eB0V16yZlk2YLMdbZ1w2b7P36ebpy/yIbP8gPsFjkwQwjtgrKoT/EEaAVqGVWlQk6OCknlSX6LNBRLDnsT9yY8Nkpf66r2IZS18Ig6NdLSAnQFrdUlqn1V51JHODfffW2UXEIdMIRFUx0WuaBLP7VE0hXnnKcyvPHd77KHvvWyHVwZtUX/cuJn0n79l83u/Vt6s4dEodZs/76X Bl4FKxrz6kNNgAlSyvHSsTzansP1kajxjvMDbSoeH3bdt42czNrsLRxOkcCmA7yEcKJh1V7x4F/C/w4FadINirbardszXa/ffWBU7b3KA0QukUtrNRz50Ffx xUZcHKGXH4R1jwjp0/QVOI4nGKAiSBR9dIuE7Ug0EMg FBc5mbbBTW8lO/kLBBYGtfmp61P8WCzcchwRMcpGbwHKp5CrdEAm8gh7VEk3OVrtqkUDC09WJ04/EzvlQZeLunSlxcvoo4fmaB5sxyjRCI9S BKh31vFlr5/b3vjuSFCJL/G6SeKhp0cf0s5tsAO2xvr6yXfO2d9jDj 61hZUJO9U5z/x80Xa8i3J8jv06QjnvnrCT07Pw7HSuvEl7ca5kH/03jj3zAloZ/rQbz8YYvt3ZTfhp2bpyxs45Zx2IgaQM/PThyDM8aARuL/UuU0EeYCG0IVVyAHmHfwX Rpob/faVv523J/bM25q NebnRug2vQC0/D6WKLZ0hs07TVsxsiJ6jp61E5aFcyqyEO7ImM2dbJAMyUXtSbzqElvMTdrwFrM/ Dl6FlD 2WgWQ5ojhCjnYJ3kG5F32gzKWzaPNilGL9o6JD/6ukdCTAvApAWHyRDFGNcAbSCqPEXUspDaCjCzDs2wsLRAbiPkcCHn7juuJrUkLF8cgauhUwTMGs2PUukSTulV9gMZN56zKe7s15YHbakyQQzfbNvPL1I0qJ6YhVB71RZPE4NgLZdbG xV/pz7TpAT3 88xWuq38OiqB w6AAG9Yoday07CK9C98wBKcxP4RU9bDs8SCoFzUDy7S5SQZMIXO6pA1yt53bGkPOvdi3Y9Ezefv2ThDTC71e/MmNf/953gHXPIoybYqOhPnjoHA2a3sER2zRSptF/wiKq2RPHxCFRhbtXU/Rcap3BXtuEQOHzv0m02at6ah7ENEdvmcXFe9KoCFoqX8X7C6EQcmL2mjgvJMZPxKjFaAx1WEzBzAQ6Ix40hqurPe4O16Doouqv8ezLUO8BG7YAYHHe9553RC6u5FJcNImxfexqOdNnUJfcjGvXXXeDDQwP28MPPmHLCwmbX8ZCyQ jk5tsbqFr471k/aaS8SxZvmhBftgOHFhHV2zcAE42P71E3L PQoX/cfaJVQcmjlmxD6mFN0iyLluLtmONGmCYXANwhcJe4QEXINFUrSJFcddbdwMxn3X46hcjO3w8spvfRmODUFKZmbI //OtvgKUPAHVXoBsAAWrmwC0VKB47EHrmkLApmordUcRmF9vR8Go6cTTBlUC5xmc/YbaJ2qqUm0YdQYwGejt4T4FiEleis4Yshb/9mEuiGBSDCNLpiuiPO/AYDn2FCE6nRaLJUvCpWxP3dFQNU y1CDkry4s2OzePxJJ6B3dxPviBO6hGRBypUnOBeZ6ND23mTSixgbNXXXmtDY5P2n33PcIDhrZ8asFqVMLDxQgrD23NQC9uhVVwgyHle83psVePZoCd51lvKW8NEqyTepH4Db3QfZpkU7drdm5DgsGdtSDcMuPg4AGqw95YWugkcX1CRxJCuqWuEUEnci60wZ0Fm4M/ rM/YkNgC1vTpzCEQ3blFX32P3btokVH6S7yjw1boY3Xk0tYH12zCMo31zOCEm NHT9ZtkVnuznDV9o7bura/V9OWqFQtd/5X3zrp06AcqIFyfuB4tLkqxoKixTVcSBqHQQlvsfD9APykFRnwvTS63gufQG6VHv21SzXlyfBm62ZjFMo7KdaPqtlQRUkuDC/aHMzxGv 33n/PR IxtmiOpZfo9sy0bPJtp 32U7OvAo/krF33XiLZfM99q37H4Tnrtgrx coyFI22V wY6eXbHKYBgols5JjgJs1aGyeOIFUY3CCPgCeICkIHbKWOw4uPhgTWtdfsz2mrDtBGfp1u6WoG6oUK0B0YCMhyDmNxc3GBU1aCgjbQj6i0uVB/o6Yv  Fh 3yc7u2cd0ExVzGPv/AU/bcS0djFVkRaz3B4hQQ7G6iwq2Bu8tjm6y hFfwHPnkpK00LyVBw8Evn7QRb8Y 979eaCNlrJpIMlDifRIqMImZKDVc/k4RgmLSTmIsKtUaiTQJWagecygvwPK10A3C1OEDoZ2zDipelAKrXgZ3SAMlvbAcZXa YidOVW2hpgr3nndHk8j2IvjwAMayRVw7Z NmeA4aFKmaXXfN7RBm/fb0Iw/RWqzb3PQKbte0gf5 qy4s0qWasBU2bQUpoYMrUs7Y7iOo33DrvmLOliguHARFmQjKAhXyPD3Ou955AYUKOJk2Zc3bZsE6EM1as5WXcVXQ3gAURKtzlAekqAl7rAWnk98LPUUAACAASURBVASaqYf7yOPH7Gvf/bpdtiZEveba2OaN9oX7p222hnQkhG1NLoE4FqAReuyKbYN2cBr0RLHUBxI5PNMkNJUtLJC7mpT7tRpJtmC//x/eZptpf1YJQ0NiQ1gsyQ4NyYzvCsqqZVpn4WkiwddkpA0iiYchOQq1RJscIGLyyaeWbdM4EkO8oqYii5cN96GfhslQBCNQ8NrIFmbMDk0R2j7w0Q9G/SiwUsCfen3e1o1vsQ0bNtnxKYSj8ON33/Eh9JEF 5svfcFOkKmPTZ2GR0lYmc7OYmXFxkfHsCAKFJJORX1KyKh9 09bDk1NfzFvS/OEA8J9u5G3fB8FR7VhOy/cSAUsRHWB1YpbLbmeh2Xxkxh84xU19 F8kKN3wM3JVF8sC4wCQhGqhgeenKLViHvP77N tDW725vsy88CWVE7h4vPYIXfpj8MOl8GptIWzdKjCGiJJlzCAZ2q4V7Y1OEBG0Rd/PwrxxBGle33//0tdu5oiUqcHsMmjAADgHrBVMH hCNHUhSpM2gLtin8khRZbdYrzb1JEt4hwSJos0MH6rZhDCKPjaVKtd3H27Z9Iz0P6k0ckXAV152xlxw Qdj5lX/7c1GR1lwX3ryGrj6Lrn7npZfbiRm0K1AF77nng5YHiXztz79kBw4ftum5pZhUG nFPiuLNjYKXFysWF/vWjvVOhLL45bm1feEIaQvvNBCmYYVONL5Q/8CgO36ndtjabbjbbfF7MXm9hNyZHFLbMJpihOu4SVQ0fUP0VGSwtisMkvTJDxmx47WrK HTEDJ/8W/OWKjmUvsWAHPTTr2wiNzgIa/pC4g UMShgXSOyHCR7/ZRSDlS22MhzvFcyjLZgAUNdqDBfvUR26wneeP2dGKOHqzQSx1op88RuLPYoCBRMPEDnWfxORLNR1i3drQJHEfEZ6dYsPqy20bRMvaKxjJTS/gPfkeumkgJNE14v5F87Bvdgzrdz79Kx PyljhwhyqYNxneM2EXbplA8mJxedFN7P4pb4  /MvfMGmT5yyRZLFCbpZ60fWkkAWbGxkMIZPl1z8Ltu9 3GgWAP2E8QwP2vlVNmc3lW5RRJlVxfV2goWdMkVW4jlqAaak9zYFjpQo7BDYGKCfoEYu0hVvHZ8hDsuWv 5eAOS0aXnKeCi/TZ7epkbP2EbNw4jYxmyF57IWm6MZDrnUNxVrV35W8vVThKqHFumT9HOwlDSUy31ohM9RQPdH7U119xle5590oY7PyCBLthP3XKFffi919hJqA70UOQgs/EBfg4ZjOE56D7iPoB4H3J5rMFP8CIpIdSzgQywqamAaOCD9JZsExWwqy76eD hBqkj6FOYSHIVUf9CqcfQJKNS/lC0beO5dujgUSzatb7BMduyfsxaqgyBTzfe/U7rGeixL/7pfwc2ztjUzAyNE4Sza0ZwHxrlaDodKNSL3narfe/p70K4VWz30WMsJJZPLmkho5BUpgZS6qXR7uJ/V12 HaiFygdLzEIx1LtoO2l BxRZ0mnOwgZuAi4M0Nrcd5LERbwdCI7xjznYQ8g3mieiKtroJOfn8nbySA5KIYvW8jlrztOYqeRsOaQfgGa0wRCDQxfJgSxLgcOD7ISNb1lrJ/ftM7/2AxZ1wbaMFe0zn/5XNidGtApZiOUPDFBVQCu7KKRFzolsU7vRY/Uk0pLsMJan8xeFtoI50Ne1fa8QisXIooEvonSrgh6l1lOyVUmgX qCVqWw 7Vf/Lnosgsusqf37IlVC2NrN9llO7YDF49CXoV21Q23gUgCe 6xR2124aSdmKIEp0TuKSMDIZGODPVj5Su286aftoeeuJ8drturJw5It2xlsH11hR4t6rYAr/JSvVhTYOfuWB jEfVbMyx2UwppBKoeHI5ajjP10NYPbbN1kxRsB4jLXWSKOfh0xpVkfUnpcNQvFu/LgEVXnLpCGw37sEXxn5gkDFGyEg6OH2ja4WPHqYRp71FXpHp823eI5BJN2WKdJn4SAwLNfO6zH6OPKxUHknMtPo5XIW/09 q6KCBY5JgGptqVIlr/djW1ojYizwYjAxip2zIiqXVr lA1w vI2AAKecau1O1SV1mJXBW4FM/Of/x3vxpdSYz/7pOPkdEdW795m11/wzW27/svEJ6Tds3N11m2VLRdX/iqHTpyHIyKfAQGsad/mORTs8k1a6xOKLjptnvs3od2kRhXbP/RA7F0O6POPZ2vgJohgYy6RVutCfPXwiJbWOT4 KidM7rOehMwoqgBpBBoKz5LhZzp54axaAYjsmxUmrZbm JHZburrlQGnl qBqmkea GGv0gl4CFb6Glz4AyYg2Q9LXMQjVIgLI4iE6AAUlbdQS/E3FDvGrr1o6jB4WGJo4HGCE1plEPobDoAE/ZY5roYhnU4JUgSv1aVboyZoAPWiBiOXVAB7o5AWz2aaQ0IOek1k4DqyVUqQIccvE1aBpBvjk3v ua6Pz124BRqMHArWMbzrEPfugue Br34g94R233MKD5O2Rex 0Z3fvtemFY9YG70/00xIkQY vJ/bPrdgd7/ug3f/NXSS6ZXtm/9H4Z/vE6S9NcW3XSpT7RhirQDEHcO1LkF2L6O zVJ4fuYY2I2EkJLEFWlA4lQSWK8XCsZOEDRbEgWvvG/CxMMaAKArV9E7CxavnqsE512fhECx2QuoLqRQo0hkXs VpY oGSx4DcxN7UWZT7KGKMBRqQElHaIh6JpQ0UVUlG kyvSILJ7pBayNl4d9JbZ5WWhJHqmfJdrh1vC9mmKUOjwN7EDdZsGq1OSSU5vX6I8sXzQwuiEOgDN0p9g5EjfYy5b5jo6CG4Ynz7Xc/ 9v21Xvvs21b19vll 1k3CVl33/4Xntqz0u2/ SMlfHnYUZdHErntZProBYCu V9d9nffO2v2ZAl23/4AK5InNRcVYWyHs9JkPy6xMUtDFWsHVcJDudSp4iBNZXSXjNP6VgchTgWUarDAudo8Dzw7KJNV5hiYSpxiHtcpCHvULm / JS3LNVyS8kVYU67kZjhAi4ei2UBlPIlUugEI NGN1GeCBxQx3RPKmzSNMsALJ1kW5yEcIZzWUsGnWcZCrUBdLUd7FWWHOgJaUUkFFoBX3uqkaJrym6aeGFyDSbodgeS1WgnMUJqbqNf8XF2OrmxX/0z0whGUnXmASXqzOVpLvksftJyGWvR3NLGfqhaeRvx7CkCtUsbCGEW4ok22Abc/AnOSznss3n2osH9sKaTiP8Z9vJFwWqZiaweK82Vleg4b0eXmfYNmyS/A8LkjpBEgsYwYzckyKtIzErpJDgnaYc2xQ19P1RfYEsANMrEFIN5OOXUGSlaYIH4OwUwxVd7tFPDBEySPIwblwSqQnwr0p/GcnH efT6oPmiaStp5JL nBI5JouXlmAiiZexv0HX8SY1kdzACRgR4hJKhRCCyyyvfwqsvGL6NdqkWNFxOrCS8gFI8H/i2aBZJOKV8YRE3Bv/svxs4issVDJ69TOS7CgDVyCwRbz0ZoniHENkEqEq2bAVHWoSrk ZUHcSJYCyaXz47MoMeMH8RTWsfQkmh3x3hBVnnT4JKk21jA4OGD/08/eRX3AQIFaiEISEHuyQHaEgoyCCPfUZF CScaGegwFngwwHVIk YwfabpP9xzwgDUWKI9SIoLrT2DiUjw7LhCP12gtFldOMSnYpp87CZymkKQ//NALJ B4wph2Dik9b72oCJ Pt8HrZMQv8fwBEM2D2ohcRn4IoWABS/K4 w42bAcbqTkzwcw4hMdmLA5H7/iT/3J8pnfjvYnVYBrNER6XVI9eKFRBAbjVqJIweahmlX4lA89duGQNAMeqboKbMrf02sr XY1rUkAlUpJ7gxTYPJeHkYomAUnVYTPKZd8uWLfdPvWxe9ho2n40KjREJ7dNEO9lQY4AsdwTk1odYyZOxlp7VoH70eInmYRsq4kNdZEFHGDDsbTPTQ7EI556jtCl uYePMKIxzOqgKNco5Ht2wpSlWVKzguhBBLQKZq9SqiRogpWEywEbY8qVlOJz7wkhEUSBjrftDNnNXr2Y QRxfCzEeUfvfguQ6sS88Mrx83hBOnY5wEa8NEeVZY0XoZrq6BoIJ9gqWH4BLdYaLyBH4rhVP/wiE2dIJsRT5PsSoeHivAUX4uPq7eZKklR6tEcox gBkfBPv6 W yqS7eiPNQEIuowMVASs/JvaWkkWFL SiGt6zLZkaURLjKrw9MW8bYOeSUAhzMVQBhRf4kKlhCkIkjDeL66T1IiSPCqheTNEzRzXIJ0rEpDqhIy6CG6QNidn461mxH3p6StjZb3heSVV2kTzK1wn3x/uMe1c0ZQzWElZAfedzWOSxB JrCvusLrfr3Zd5yBwVzUluwaKNclNuboYk2sK9ve/QdsI1SyhyogIJ6ICp05dRDLEsbFOrhwoOk0hSjFPWKnXCgVkyIKC1gHbTyN50hr3 H6BTBbAtZQ/M8SwqpSMW3/12d 1fqpCLv4cRO8pkE3uh1UvlpALFe1AJqYtBCOJNkYhq9Nil zKuvzkIbEk/HkCN1TCuKrASNaSAkBET41lox4q61xVmZzQ8Z3cjqyQKIqQp9eo85ZmutEGufEUCTUjdT/ZfHVHFH3ST1SoS4lYu9MTFc4lSZ19ZeSbBxGzgaj15afKBj/0l/KEfG/h0aHowLqgfn5o9Yk9v6nX/oLkl/H/uRLf2Lnj19p 6eP2vBILwrbV 3xxx5Ak685Vywbwaf DmJ17urUhtS9cddHv2lap/SAbJbLAqJeR xEQILpVKVYWZq33v6SfeYXP0ZDPUMDBIwM5uZFLHKGJC5NBT/LEQRSGcdISA sDhN/14n1ybyGKMDqzGcB5eNzE0KKmIZUzlhHSQ0OLD1k4Tywv5ZInhghhjo e8z6x8pWpoGj5J7inlRnxHp8NtWVQkGdZUJpCkABxuKndfSBXnN2qvHsiupe RU3Vv4Ri1/I5qJCbwlKGK0k04IfvvsznJ/Qskdffsgu2fA2m59N2tCwb88885S9fOyBOKnEZxnEgqEz8EkPxUY0NIslSYRwroofWSBMlcYxDamGm1xgwWiq0zBfWMHKKUTu2LnRbrvjxnjIzaUR4sNAKqlG2jgKqiRhRNFXIWeJpnEOq2xTxWpeQLg7qXMYsMQ6YUmhkP8D7SP0JSRI1CvExHbFg9pVoO5//fq37aHvPkPTvoTsJbIdoz32Hz71CYS9SvA0xxlB1Wyuco/Sjgg0H vPabRJ46waZFPjSThdz696ICZtXgOVb2r5r7nA6/7BLBtiwThrr2KlDZsvjx/oyNQhG113qZXhQipzp6ksZ 3gwcfxrB/O6LF no0oFot06WkOq/xm8eNRGn1PSmH OBkVShQ19ESLLOySFAEgi23nDNuvkXiLWFqCxY wLMXfLBXkMtguDeTLkCgTrPQKYUdj/QnRuRrt5G8XllTzrh3Yz4CCqEdzUNLtg540pNzS8IIaReSgP/nSAyCdg3Eh6JBIuzB2A4CASZR0H/nAjXYZigrJvKVUjo2Le25TjQp6l lWtYnrlKKx0Csud OSV9XvP3HxMyl6RxreEm hGSmdoUAw1ZxorgxnomYxSasM/p lwNK0e9w8Vqzjt J/gUHnJgpcXUcDvnH ObPDujGHzQzpDrlUhmt64dXxzoM0ZUKKqAs3jtq// Q9cVJOEct1sIYUw2lEWx1CjKczEzQOFDerOW4lDi8kYyVyJXveRzC1rVqFr6eApl1QkDT9bcRKSvJMazH00bHPfPb3UVa0bVHjSFInUz UWdh miu3vv0i 8RP3wx 0DE1q6ImoSOfzZEk3QdrSjqYEiLCy/34xBKZ7OpARwzVXnvqfxjz39TyASa0b5VMVhNmLJWIJ 1URmsTRAcpVlIAiaeWL/KrQ zvpXAqMNcUUhRFYP6p6eMkkxh/yhR 6P1kLB6rvmPjONqVJTs5u8iCJG1kpGS//asfX50o5yEEC13YTheEI82lFME6vyBL EHZHguSUjHDCBzEC2OOkXywogY5RJ7itwYSJHDtSG9PK1FzuAmoiF//3J/Ynr0nGPudQw1BSASN0atCb TbrTt32K998r1xYahqNh6yppOm9/Z0XbU4pUY4Qy17bIAjWBtD9DPPGm/Am8f8N138RNJFdo6VgHS0 LqoS/Ghkcz 4hCwjOoSbIygk6/xNmgPY16bYqo8fi506YTdevO19uWvfclOndpDx4bvUYzIJeUV2kS9Xlp5RlxAIEqULBzwr8mQcX9/r/3Wpz CppNYL GReB2KrQ7zvdA3XMe1XjpIiuEZ5r0CrDvTVhWugTiSOAuQkz6S 0uJ5sWauzq/QSeKkIBrGrgAwaRAKvfd9x37o10PE6IgueiWwS/H5zJQHNuHrnm7ffrf/lQ87OdCVSuHOay46gNJWuImCkk5Dc kZ0pgFAIAGuJw4vfVHvwjF5/d5FoqhxXLQcwUWZrG84mfYaxYJqSgsVjVyGsyZTXmSzLXy8DwDTs/bov8fvLFB61x hBQj2wFJXAWdcXXVhwFCiqM KodCEMpNkCHTOi0p8/91ieBm3gMDXefBVYhl8UqNWoj2rgkOCvYiQVmCBcJPMLNgPHFfAlKAofDeDKF8MaCSMbHPscQUHHai8888O2xbz1hX/3mk6icadhUl6g3WDQq9DzylbdfdLH9p3/3EfNLsKHSXeI1aTp8qyOgeDIJPwINqggTqlMfV9My8WkjqzXu6xb/9Xb  kT8w/bv5HLgfJ1dowfl8Isys7Qr83VGgJisYENi7lrJUxlBc7JnFFyOGsx4SB/KsTrzVtiXdRh7FNqJJzT5/tnX6i0FzwLNWhGuda8qin1tUillvyuszwiQzvSRRl/0YAZg7MLhVFGLZ8kNwzTEU3m08Zq9ImYn2Lw6U4MeXSZP8dtTSCIOY5HS93RpyMQsJKGupqNkuJ97/2yXHTt 0vYeO2Evk9yF23uW6V4BWS9ev9l 5zd LR5FSjDgrXymKfk4gOqZsXpxPx7PLK QesHXwSBiQv9B2PkJF/81y1dzAv8boz242Jix2gKaQpFQZy99JoOeDSOqELsikOSOsgbJnrG0 GWve60qzfiXkAm0cZf/11iOI9im ShQzmd 4 fR2UA/KMHpyDCsPYL3/9Jf7UJzudXWrpuMO88pXDzJFIq0GAoBETIVV5p44nZAnT 5ZWD1NBHkB4AUFp8BOe5RoCGLt 3 7lP2/Se/gwhgzp6Zgd6EL9IRZHVi/gCN9E/c R4ro8rYsW2Sge5yvLg6RkBhWCdVxYQfxvjot58k1N4Z099ibunXr4bXuMpdrXX PvmesXxeq3FuARU9ebyhcCSRxu3rHI8y3L/JPvDef22PPnIvSuCHiWVvzsi93qLPesPZTTkb58W9rE7jrXqASDPF/TRUtAYElBRlXWnGeO75mRuQ9eWBm4QdDEnSPB3Z9ehDr9hv/eb/bSPjE7E6TFRHSDgQoaLfEfWGI4E7D/TUdx ke7UIKkEqyEXaTAm2SD4NQpRUEKqgi9Dbf/o/EALML2BgAITZllW4zyyq5pwaR5dcaFN0wu 662q78Yod8VlvErc2xFSy Qkqc8cv2u/ weft9/7L7/EMq03x BgHHnH3C7vt4gs3xIhpFYfp19nFV1R07PBJpvg5UibW53NmQBzzNYi6bvJ8OPyr7cTijL34 FfixXktzJzBtD8ctX78/8UNCZ2bwELH/HcMO2WtqzerwycC6IhLr95sH7z8IrpRJGYsdAAaVyHj5SeX7FO/ X9Sb0zEpFZSBDq/usR1zVDFfnemVt/37PcgA4 gvWGLCUsu aq2oglAVBmgoZgSIIE wvkKL/zgGLh/0abAra3lWeI7vBILrQP2yoSp8Y0b7D9 4qfxFsAFuU9He3mEtCZls3ie//bfv2p/ Ef/FQBA7lK5ccbT//LPv2n33PN2DEJ54g2LH9t9wh7//m7bCbKKA4QWXxWrRhkzyKu2Xn67zb26247sfYrk/aO56Ncv  s94Y2Vb/wm2gQsr9DPWWNMcauQ0TiNhsTaLH5iqMcKSKh1MqDk2uez2DfefD2N8RX7mZ/7FVu/BTHNW/z6wbNPkEOO48GIYnXwBB6ywBhOF2TUEEmXx7tnp20KAe5f/s2TNoowy4GdbcBbHWgmGXei00Id0QV8JnJ5iioWD p867qNtmFkIj4dax33MYz49rnnnrX3/QwgoZ pFpUcZ 7tscefspsu3xKHJicWasop9d3V8VJNq y6/zt2 83XxB4TL368QBRSfcN0h3qHUQRUrMGhdz/p4r9 Xd64 KtqXoEK4m4fXSpCUVwvaHiB5BoBIUfK9Ak4HiCJsNHBpHtouN9z3dVWHNho777747Z2w4a3Wnt75nvfgliYptDjxENCqOiEecRcTdEOhLAwNWqf dwfE99LNkMlvp7QNoJxVbsVZr1AXrRGNRgRQCVkGMILRboRPvon1tA6nacSHrDxUtm2jW60kbVb7LZbbrUxFByARagKVfn8OM WrC irOAQMXk1eS2kRxBSaQqInDg9a9978hW768ar6AuzQRQrsRhC9KrkEL39E7YwewrXVcZ665j/xlV5Yz44mwOkZohEEav0J8RJ167LJ0E0bYjDEnG3jcyvwGlX68uTdsHQiK3dssNu/fAv2cZNiOjf4tdzTzyOquIIhdtsPB8lbeXyHIUcCrkMNcOfPbrfnpziLEwmQ2qQeh7nM6RpjueYiJznMKWs5IgQeDqWxdW5OvGclo8BoC/SYXyoiscQ4Ayu2wRw6IcDu8e 8I2v2YGpg9Q3q6rmPq6pdlkHvVGJ59K4aUM9X7isgeIAHgW/CpB4301XsAHXCkEloniBKP9HEMluOu/t9uR3v0yypAj5YUr6tcd/s9Dyo9bm7OKf/b4wtAaHRRfHSZMq0mdavQfdZY0aoUgQHWfUdAts41D/gP3Cb/5nm0C  Fa/XnzuKcRVexlCIOzwO A9lhZnoZabaGR67S8eeQlKuc5inbD6Ag0W4GsEY5kh9NRIwOqCq1rtUFzqCJgUErN6fFpg3QYn19oyirltg5M2WVxDkoYVRad6DI3QRVsm0YBWGT8t2KsosgsAizHCt7Sh07NMIhKWBgd7OM8ohYB23KY5vygBvP7D3/oNQWtVuOww0yaDfVvshvd zD7/B5/hhCeJCd/qkf/h919v W/ 0zrXgJhPYlUMFFOoftxI2bPhYcRM00dsI6riLJMqW0cn7Zc /b/bunO2vuWNvLznKVuYeh6qez4 f1MbsMhxBTXEsE/Mrth3D5y2Mp79Cnqk1iz1CFRzVmJfND15ph0XCXfxPeE1KeoGByttUIAVOP hk0U7TrG5FQ6rAM2B3sEOnjoNRcFxj26DhYWvInovMlI0yAGBm i0v3hkifEqVcNN2zQ2RMUNxY54eHHetxuvvMp  aO3r8Z8QU0JW7cUL7Hr7/xZ 9wf/Toy6iPAtrP89N8/ 1sv7o9ep7Px/ w1IiEfdYPYhIJkJgmErTzEZk50zdCP3b5h1D7xP/9vtnnbjh yA53YGuepuPZcrbhPHz5ie1/4JonzEHSDJitD CNGhDpp /6eA/b8/DKLw7DG/GGjs2gBRGCmj2R8gmEHFsYjIUd0vlzkDjorgQGCWNkaZdQ8Qb2MUtvoaWvDNg tsZd2P28zHNeYCBF0oUfKkUumK1M2MrCGoewhmz6OEaBn7aPWGESqeHK bUMDg7YAV3bjZdfZ3Xe exXnq1TOFgdtXe92u/Ha6 0//7ffpo04TTvx7/n6tzS9H/OCN YBCU7jAyk0aQg9kNa5OSVKeayohUUOr8FtSxN28 UX2 13fdS2n3vB6ujkapNs9Ty1WD3G/5/pIkUInx7a9XkoCXT9SurE7/nGHF5AnuE80Ae /bztVgNdc7bw/DXUaC5Uh7uEqIvXJkA2bWksgZ R8CPnD7mMB6V1jjKxP4uyrpfmfpPQ9a8//jH7 tfutVc4fTBioHvryMXUDW1Q4iH2rM/GJhAPc aolMwBnkLSAYk5dgXP8cqBQ/anv/c79gf/z5dXLT8G/DyHWn/S3rd1EAQZOj7Q4f DX29cfBFtMecjKCsWUyU7CSqnbjRFUx5tqOSFO0b67O7bPmib126EPWWzcG fe9LJg3VidYspvwDSD5Aah5hTc4ett0xHGGdoIKBcqCyjKeKUc0762Dd11B6ZQk23H2qCwqlLLI xIB05UQc6WYQGL6QgQVoqCg7pbkE2JhluS9OO7O9nkIOBO9T59uFbb7NdD yyvYiJdX553/ga5nyZ2mE216X1mMFzdPwAU0KgnF7W07fR3rINMfoyi5F84kOftB8cOEXMF2EugzpTRJ21yn/Omsuq4w19i8JMJxLGFTKhR2entXRyFWPa/Zx15tLYXssDb117Hq6MJIQuVl1TCzRPLtxETmCsSKc9S 8eNhm2g XUaR5tGuoixTwq1gqnnzh017ILS/bc0ZP20HTbTk/R0AFeqoPkEFbSOkNBPWZUCepDd OT7FYlaD7VdzfD/WlB6TcX6bB1ScjXXf12e/w7j9nUEhP34vuZcAw5T05zwCmG/Ia53wzUB INOw6EN0RpQ2xanUTeAXD88Wf/2IahzV/D f UxT4bw99skX8U5Hz9Rkv5G8cRWfMahhOQb/iEieGREZLviB1 ZdruvmIbD89Jt VRO3SSBEo4mOhL2YbJYkxd1Fi0JEJUHaPL6fbxsZKLx6eYGQBirrRs06UXIgeH6i4n7fN7Zi2As2rzmkBH7IJ24hYk3S5p94OYw1Y/Qawfagcq3jxwtIQudJ5JxZAJl95sn91yzZX29W/cx0mxHNahE00QiLWRoYi9SXG0WIYiTayqy/PVqPCL9KGL5Ic5HfcC9Z0niZSYhH/LxT9rxa9ftH/KRr3 Z862HlcPrIbCxeIku9OJey3OUbvwyCsOfwAABwVJREFU/AuszGEbz//gCbt865r4RI QuJnvydorexmaQCcYdTjzn4eswVssQwguVk6z8Oj5idc7b7zTHn2Q4ygZjE1xaFMvH4ZQ7O3YN188bqcX4ZaoJSCY4vMdXAa9dHIusTdWJEgzpGPlI6SDbRpFpQIzynhVi7A3N4un0EMuMlVYbeAdSOArnEmX4HStLAWZDgdvMgvQlQQRbVeSirkpGQoek4snG Gcgl4OyUYFSM/8LRf/n7vQP 7nX5NTYGh5xUmKoRmo4AEWvsmQxLkk3vUjaPfJET1MueR07hrnQWjSklMdkCXWGKfHG3SWzSyHbfCQy4vTMcEbYm3IjTh4r8FhFFUbHe21XScyduLwND1qmvBIS3R2gs4V7qAN1TFeSRhVqSR0QkWHhN4dkZIO4o2c0PYo0GikNGfoQSwRusgPAbqeLpMrrrgfRUTeMIlBJNESBky9tOmKJTmcKYBvylOAdchnTarpCD35xhKdubP0wr/kIr/ZteOEe/YbUqVhzUnK9Abi2R1r1wogcHRwOz6MGoZGJ3rpeAmaLyAZ2nlNTuuLGOdvwglFxNIF1HQdqlLNT n8e52jWSXeFnjteqrd67aN2xenuzYLPo QP pAJZdFamP5EbE6pqhj9k94X4fe0VhC1hzlaUkyoZLEAGqEseaiPuSBNBsf68snTRB2dK6E4CphX6fbg8xI4Nx/F51rl/6Cjo3PACr02QMOR/0Cbpm4pND8/2vxz1bJcVhTGxqDUxetxowtOTU Elc6a9UCCkuaacowbJDpUW0AEQY/VJmD/xdg4oQrHdGuT6bQgXOxtpM80gCxSVR3OZZ 8Y6y/eWpnE0dOb2qO4L59HQujsSxeJSO hI kNfoIw30YQaskPWOrqWxdArvAnaywM0FRJToiloi8Un5EPLxuUI68KJLFy5N0yc M5/ziHTUUZrQpcO8RS3LuybG1tu73/Vx 8pfff5fdvF/0oIsPteSeK9OotTNyFnijwOJP9RFHS2p4VjlfC jRfzdQl9TRwndruApxHUviwUz8 VgdiOU9mqgJFAwZLnmURQXF9AaBLjY49PEcUQ5EkB1mDZRzzieOMH6Y8EXvL1CnMTCTR0HydxXc4WT2zjdpC10AkLaOLjV9j33PBbNBpE7XMZBXXHlOuyO0OID1yVOjD sh ukuV6VuJ8iVkqymGQwRNoiBqX ZRf/JwllsSJYJ3xw/3J9Ef1pLKdKW1NH  pw0QRi3Q4hQpJBEJ/5Q8zQMsfKcaC4tz6ehh5z3COQHJBGO0VcgREUxuvij9iYP8mUoj5FQpvM66QB0nnIq32M1Y/7WG2IqHjTJyOJ6klanmKpDV0RoH4QFG7D5 i8NJ1LFP ADMYrA1MJW1K54WlS5jlMsOvTghydQpJX25MGPjL0FFVyHzqkBvNn5QEa82fDzo DjT/JIv5zXqPuqHq GUr8KjFeDGOHZrUnihn4KLd3wc0pHqp/GCEUiW6OkaTWApsDIRZx2hNKxLiqzVFktWEyBzkTogVPr5bdMmOgZI YSdVHi0jqqDChmkaH9sabRuiQberfHVZS3FBygLF qu6IRr3qTS AclhZXBUI87MuskodtKoeT4oWaZNjEELO89HhSm3FfRr iZIEBHyWALWAxxRMir716fhDdtikHxfzf7Tm9h /1D8qBMUPjtWsik0l0MIY9WDyTBbfRc2sQ1W7UL8iw/oL5AUo28UuQ7skUGl8dMyyVNGhRjRBTD6bMMBHTc0ucrQuCTSJ8sDvKfEavIX5Ap F1qHaDUg0KduUd3yoDuUMdaDiRoiChA4EyemDcfgMMJJ/PH 7rDPgsGw8snvmAxt8hSs2B5UlNAQ/QziqQUG7mhtg9iuNukKn7wbcf1qzYz1IEmuva6a8KSJ53Rd/UqLhJ61uz15arz9TZMejQG0tCAsa6rwaHetI3aMPxxF60Gfl5Hr5Hl2laUKAo0Y5lqfPZ3HJE4FOg9LsFli/B3XDQWZjRR0IKbnog/QpRl21GFmsFB0sfaqEtLlxZy0OIzofZ/XjReJeMQ3z3j4d5QUbSdsxqbMYCGVt6GVNpMeHNCGrSapposMw4kEQ r5wRvqIqJCjiiV3zGHtFVpeXXctrz9keQq lo60J/P/EL3wQ8XQGdOXQkFFyBsr2bOh6o0F2JuFsLPo5vU/8xrBBq2ga8fHuBNwUySzqk4OAdM3gJJiLn19yAyVIUckW0g46ExXoX8xeWZ31YNdHYqS0g3rw1p7mD6fO8K5B/q0CEixRRY7hbc0qWxDoKmq24jkm1CCJ3S1CCWyZ4mkNISl wE8xkgqPlxNSmV6Hj7eVaN20KksqHY4IVefOsTMre4B4Veb8JgEDjfiM/41c6L5MFaQ7wVk9wSbohPEG8yW/b icjF/ndJSdAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg: ="}
```

if I try to send the base64 URL through the postman the application crashes .why don't know if anyone know the issuse plz help me thanks in advance

Comment: Your base64 isn't valid. I saw several spaces. There's also a `:` later on, which is also invalid in base64.

Comment: Your base64 has 372 spaces and 1 `:`. It's not valid base64. If I fix that, the length is wrong (not a multiple of 4), and then if I fix that, I get a PNG file that doesn't render. You can use the following regular expression to verify this: `[^a-zA-Z0-9\+/=]`